# What is the correct CircleCI image to use for Lambda NodeJS 10.x?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, circleci

I've just been trying CircleCI and am working through setting up its config.yml. I see from the examples you need to provide a docker image. Such as this, from their provided demo yml:

```
docker:
  # specify the version you desire here
  - image: circleci/node:6.10
```

My application runs on AWS Lambda using its " NodeJS 10.x" runtime. Which, according to https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/aws_lambda_adds_support_for_node_js_v10/, uses the latest minor one.

Given that, I took a look at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/#nodejs thinking there would be a "10.x" equivalent. But the ones beyond 9 seem to have names. Hmm. Which is the correct/best one to use given this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. Use the image `circleci/node:10`.

All images have a version number, but LTS releases also have codenames as provided by Node.js. That's what you were seeing, but there's still version numbers.

Comment: Ah ... I didn't see a 10 listed. There was a 9.7, 9.8, 9.9 ... and then ... named ones. I didn't realise you could just use 10 :) That solves that, thanks

Comment: We're working on making browsing the Docker tags easier. Coming later this year. :)